# Can't add support library v7 AppCompat

Tags: android, eclipse, android-support-library, android-appcompat

I can't add support lib v7 `appCompat`. I do step-by-step like this: [enter link description here](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html#libs-with-res) (see Adding libraries with resources for `Eclipse`). And when i do this, i have next:
[image]

is `...extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\src` folder must be empty?

i try to remove `...extras\android\support` folder from disk and download via `Android SDK manager` in Eclipse, but it doesn't help me.

What i do wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After i re-install eclipse, android SDK all works fine with support lib v7.

Answer (score 1):

To add v7-support jar, go to build path, and add the respective jar
To add missing source, go to build path - libraries. Expand your support jar. There you will see source attachment (None). click it and then click edit and add the path for the source which is i guess in the extras folder.

Answer (score 1):

I just had exactly the same problem, see [Cannot add android.support.v7 to my project build path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20523026/cannot-add-android-support-v7-to-my-project-build-path) .

First part of the solution was to download 4.2.2.
Second was to check "Copy the project in your workspace", when I imported the support-library!

Answer (score 0):

Have you included v4 Support Library? Please make sure of that. Because v7 appcompat library depends on v4 Support Library.

Follow the link for documentation,

http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html#v7-appcompat

Comment: Ok.. Verify that you have placed your appcompat library file in your project folder or not.. If no, please move the library project folder to your project folder and then try to add..