# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.support.v7.appcompat.R$styleable

Tags: android, compiler-errors, android-theme

I develop an android application. I use AppCombat Theme and when I run my program, I have a `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.support.v7.appcompat.R$styleable`. Its logs are:

```
Process: com.nomad, PID: 12866
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.support.v7.appcompat.R$styleable
        at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegate.onCreate(ActionBarActivityDelegate.java:107)
        at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.onCreate(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:58)
        at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.onCreate(ActionBarActivity.java:98)
        at com.telera.ui.activities.OABaseActivity.onCreate(OABaseActivity.java:47)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(Zygote`
```

How can I fix that problem?

Comment: You can see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22271759/fixing-error-in-styles-xml-to-generate-r-java-in-hello-world-android-application/22271850#22271850

Comment: Check [this thread][1]

usnul's reply worked for me


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20523026/cannot-add-android-support-v7-to-my-project-build-path

Comment: possible duplicate of [No resource found that matches the given name '@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21059612/no-resource-found-that-matches-the-given-name-style-theme-appcompat-light)

Comment: Did you fixed it? I am having the same issue. @johnerror

Answer (score 6):

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   android.support.v7.appcompat.R$styleableY

You need to reference `AppCompat` in your Android project. You have not referenced the library project properly.

Check [Adding Support Library](https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html) with resources

Comment: thanks your ansver, i did it before but i'm still give an error. i spent my all day but i can't fix :/

Comment: @JohnError if you follow the link it will absolutely work no doubt. check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21059612/no-resource-found-that-matches-the-given-name-style-theme-appcompat-light