# "Hello World" Android program in Eclipse spits a hell of errors

Tags: java, android, eclipse

One screenshot is one thousand words:

[image: Hell of errors]

What Am I doing so wrong guys? Is it my face it does not like?

**Updates....**
When I tried a new project with both "Target SDK" and "Compile With:" set to "API 23: Android 6.0" the Problem Errors disappeared but I get errors in the Console tab like this:

[image: error heaven]

Comment: Is this project aware of the Android SDK? Should be linked in as a Library somewhere.

Comment: I starting development on eclipse but because of such errors I switched to android studio, it's much better and I strongly recommend it to you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26530415/error-in-styles-base-xml-file-android-app-no-resource-found-that-matches-the/27243716#27243716

Comment: [Refer this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29877692/why-was-actionbaractivity-deprecated?lq=1) @Thanasis

Comment: Hi people. Thanks for your replies. I updated info with another screenshot above....

Comment: so apparently you just started working on android but for some reason you decided to use a tool that has been deprecated for more than a year instead of the current recommended IDE? I'm not even sure where you found the eclipse plugin...

Comment: like @njzk2 mentioned above , it woukd better using Android Studio instead Eclipse if you are starting to learn Android.

Comment: @Thanasis, just switch to Android Studio

Comment: I have switched to Android Studio guys. Couldn't bother more. This year there are many Android Studio tutorials and books coming out so I don't find the reason why I should bother more with eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `ActionBarActivity`, and you didn't included it.

But, `ActionBarActivity` was deprecated, because `Toolbar` was introduced. 
See this:
[Why was ActionBarActivity deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29877692/why-was-actionbaractivity-deprecated)

If you still want to use ActionBarActivity for study, 
See this to add appcompat7: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20523124/850347

Comment: No I think the problem is broader. Something to do with settings, SDK or something related.

Answer (score 0):

Import `appcompat` library and clean and rebuild the project.

Comment: Thank you brother. I couldn't bother more. There are so many books and videos on android coming out this year so I switched to Android Studio.