# Have not folder "android" in mysdk/extras/android

Tags: android, sdk, android-appcompat

Sorry for my English. I need import appcompat in my progect. Before i import it in path "mysdk/extras/android/v7" and all work, but naw i have new folder sdk and i cant find folder "android" in my sdk

[image]

it i installed

[image]

Answer (score 0):

if you are using android studio add this line in build.gradle in dependencies

```
      compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
```

Comment: i think this could be help you.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20523026/cannot-add-android-support-v7-to-my-project-build-path